# Error executing DDL while creating an entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a simple entity, without any relationships, but when I run my app, it throws this:

```
         Error executing DDL "create table tasks (id bigint not null, car bigint, created_at datetime(6), status varchar(255), to bigint, updated_at datetime(6), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

My entity is very simple. Here is its code:

```
 @Entity
  public class Task {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;


  @Column(name = "car")
  private Long car;


  @Column(name = "to")
   private Long to;


  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Task.Status status;
    public enum Status {
     NEW,
     DONE,
     }

 @CreationTimestamp
 private Date createdAt;

 @UpdateTimestamp
 private Date updatedAt;
 }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to"is a reserved word in SQL. 
Try giving your field "to"a different name, like

`@Column(name = "to_something")
 private Long to;`